# custom css properties are not applied after custom elements are resolved into shady dom tree

Tags: css, polymer, shady-dom

The follow is a sample polymer element

```
<dom-module id="custom-dialog">
  <style>
      #text{
        width: 400px;
        height: 50px;
        position: relative;
        background: #fff;  
      }
     p{
       position: absolute;
       margin: var(--ui-connectionDialog-text-margin, 5% 30%); 
       font-size: var(--ui-connectionDialog-text-font-size, 18px);
      }
  </style>

  <template>
     <!-- local DOM for your element -->
    <div id = "text" > <p><content></content></p> </div>

 </template>
</dom-module>
```

and an example of it being styled using custom css

```
<style>
   custom-dialog.connecting
   {
      --custom-dialog-text-font-size: 23px;
      --custom-dialog-text-margin: 3.8% 30%;
   }

   custom-dialog.disconnected
   {
        --custom-dialog-text-font-size: 20px;
        --custom-dialog-text-margin: 3.8% 30%;
   }       
</style>
<body>
  <custom-dialog class="connecting">Connecting</custom-dialog>
</body>
```

I was able to apply the custom css property with the `connecting` class property , however when I used js to change the class of the custom element to `disconnected`, the new css property is not applied. In fact when the class property is changed back to `connecting`, the respective css properties is also not applied.

I suspected that this is due to the face that my browser is running in shady-dom mode and there is a gap in in the poly filling.

I am tempted to directly apply the css properties onto the `<p>` element in the shady-dom, but it will like to know if there is a proper way of dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to polymer docs "Only rules which match the element at creation time are applied. Any dynamic changes that update variable values are not applied automatically."

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html

"Re-evaluation of custom property styles does not currently occur as a result of changes to the DOM. Re-evaluation can be forced by calling this.updateStyles() on a Polymer element (or Polymer.updateStyles() to update all element styles). For example, if class b was added to x-foo above, the scope must call this.updateStyles() to apply the styling. This re-calcs/applies styles down the tree from this point."

.. as is best explain your problem and this is official workaround to your issue. You should call this.updateStyles() after applying disconnected class.